# Pylint complains about imports

Tags: python, pylint

When I try to import Protocol from the typing module, I get the error "unable to import typing (import-error)" It's error 0401. E.g. I have a file test_import with the single line

```
from typing import Protocol
```

The code itself runs fine.

I'm using: Python version 3.10.11, pylint version 2.17.5

I run the pylint in a command line on windows as follows

```
C:\Path\To\Python310\Scripts\pylint.exe test_import.py
```

or alternatively

```
C:\Path\To\Python310\python.exe -m pylint test_import.py
```

I similarly run python on the command line

```
C:\Path\To\Python310\python.exe test_import.py
```

Comment: Show us exactly how you run pylint, and how you run the code.

Comment: Is Pylint installed in the same environment?

Comment: I've added information about how I run the code. I'v also found a more general reproduction of the import error, so edited the question.

Comment: `typing` is a built-in module that has existed since Python version 3.5.  It really sounds like you are using a very old version of pylint.  Show us the output of `pylint --version`

Comment: pylint 2.17.5
astroid 2.15.6
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: I installed python 3.10.11 by downloading the embeddable zip file for windows, and then proceeded to pip -m install pylint